# how to get List of components and their id present in the given xml file in android?

Tags: java, android, xml

. I am newbie to android . For some need i need to get all the components (i.e. TextViews ,Buttons,EditTexts,Imageviews,spinners ,checkboxes and so on . . ) and their ids in my layout xml file.
say i have following xml file  `sample.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />


    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CheckBox" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RadioButton" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" >
        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>



</LinearLayout>
```

Currently i have only id of my xml file .I need to get all components  and ids so that i can modyfy their text using java code. In short i need some kind of parsing.
    Assuming that i dont know anything inside my xml file except its id.

SO please help me  . .Thank u in advance . .

Actually i need to change the text of each textVeiw in that layout say i need to add * ath the end of the text of each text view.

Comment: Have you tried findViewById?

Comment: @Nitish , i dont know the ids of every element in the xml file . .findViewById() will work only if i know my id  . .

Comment: Are you creating views dynamically?

Comment: no ..it is created using xml code . .while creating layout . .

Comment: @Nitish assume that i dont have permission to open and see layout xml file . .so i will not be able to see any id or event i cant guess which elements are there .

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You don't have permission to open layout file, and you need ids of all components doesn't sounds ok.

Comment: @SACHIN-782 i dont think that might be possible unless you create the xml thru code only!

Comment: what i mean to ' don't have a permission to open file ' is i should not open file by double clicking on it ,its ok if i open it using code . .My sinario is that I have given an xml file which has around 100 TextViews and there ids are very different e.g xyz,123a,df25fd etc . and i need to change their text. So changing the text  by seening the id in file and then using it in findViewById("abc"); will take a lot of time and code will long  .

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK There is no way for you to achieve what you are looking for.

If all ID's were created and defined in the xml layout file - you will have to call them in you code - but you will have to know their given ID's.

If you create your ID's via the code for example `textView.setId(1234);` - then you are able to keep track of all names and do whatever you want with them.

So, unfortunately I don't think what you want is possible.